# Change inSampleSize of a Bitmap

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, bitmapfactory, glsurfaceview

I am creating a bitmap from glsurfaceview and adding it to a arraylist but when I created a bitmap from glsurfaceview it gives `outofmemory error`

CODE:

```
Bitmap bitmap = createBitmapFromGLSurface(0, 0, mEffectView.getWidth(),
            mEffectView.getHeight(), gl);
al_bitmaps.add(bitmap);
```

Method:

```
private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
        throws OutOfMemoryError {
    int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
    int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);

    try {
        gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                intBuffer);
        int offset1, offset2;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            offset1 = i * w;
            offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch (GLException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

For larger resolution device (ex. Samsung Galaxy S4), my app crashes.

I would like to know how to set inSampleSize of that bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all i will recommended to you use

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in your manifest file.

Secondary if that not helped to you look that https://stackoverflow.com/a/17839597/2956344

Also i recommend to you know about maximum texture size of your `GLSufaceView` to check limit of your bitmap resolution programmatically.

[Get Maximum OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture Size Limit in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11022109/2956344)

P.S. I think you find information about use GL10.